# Starting a Spring Boot application from a third party Java application

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I'm using the [SQL Server Language](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/language-extensions/language-extensions-overview?view=sqlallproducts-allversions) extension feature to have SQL Server call into a Spring Boot application.

As explained in this [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/language-extensions/tutorials/search-for-string-using-regular-expressions-in-java?view=sqlallproducts-allversions), I call a stored procedure with a class that extends `AbstractSqlServerExtensionExecutor`:

```
EXEC sp_execute_external_script
  @language = N'Java'
, @script = N'com.example.Sample'
, @input_data_1 = @query
, @params = N'@regexExpr nvarchar(200)'
, @regexExpr = @expr
with result sets ((ID int, text nvarchar(100)));
```

SQL Server then uses its own Java application (called Launchpad) to instantiate  `com.example.Sample`, then calls `Sample`'s init method followed by its execute method.

However, `com.example.Sample` is in a boot JAR. So, Launchpad can't find it on the classpath. That's because boot JAR has it within `/BOOT-INF/classes` folder. I can't tell SQL Server to use `org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher` because `@script` must be a `AbstractSqlServerExtensionExecutor`.

To work through this issue, I created a non-boot uber jar using [shadow](https://github.com/johnrengelman/shadow). This way the Sample.class is located within jar at `/com/example/` and Launchpad can find it. Then I can start my Spring application within the constructor of `Sample`:

```
public class Sample extends AbstractSqlServerExtensionExecutor {

    public Sample() {
        executorExtensionVersion = SQLSERVER_JAVA_LANG_EXTENSION_V1;
        executorInputDatasetClassName = PrimitiveDataset.class.getName();
        executorOutputDatasetClassName = PrimitiveDataset.class.getName();

        Main.main(new String[] {});

    }
    ...
}

@SpringBootApplication
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new SpringApplicationBuilder(Main.class)
        .web(WebApplicationType.NONE)
        .run(args);
    }
}
```

This starts my application as a Spring Boot application but it doesn't find the `application.yml` file which is at the root of the jar.

How can I properly run my Spring Boot application application properties from another application (in this case SQL Server's Launchpad)? In particular, I need my Spring Boot application to be started with properties defined in application.yml.

Comment: My first question would be why do you want to launch a whole spring boot application, from a database query? Why don't you write an sb application that queries the database and performs the necessary action instead?

Comment: That's a fair question. We have several team members fluent in T-SQL but not Java. The T-SQL code they're developing needs data from a web service. They found Microsoft documentation recommending use of language extensions to get the web service data into their T-SQL code. The Spring Boot application needs to get data from a web service, do some manipulation to the data not easily done in T-SQL, and return the manipulated data to their T-SQL code.

Comment: Is there any reason you need a spring boot application? When you can't use most of its features. Why not use a small library like https://square.github.io/okhttp/ to make your rest calls instead?

Comment: Yeah, I was looking at making it a Spring Boot application to leverage its' (and Spring Framework's) many features such as DI, RestTemplate, resource config (e.g. via application.yml), etc. But I've noticed it takes about 500ms to start the Spring Boot app and it would have to go through this start up every time the stored procedure called it. So, perhaps I should just use Spring as more of library or use other libraries as you suggested.